# how to pass data from one view to other view in laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I am using laravel to develop my project.
In my controller I have Variable called `$products` and i'm passing that variable to the view ,

`return view('products.index')->with("products",$products);`

No any issue till here !

Now i want to pass same `$products` to the other view,

`<a href="{!! route('productsnew.index') !!}"> Click Here </a>`

How can i pass `$products` with this `route`?

Thanks For the Help !

Comment: Instead of passing data from view to view, you could instead fetch in the controller and then pass to the view as you're doing for the first view. Also, read https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pass-data-from-one-view-to-another?reply=670895

Comment: You can pass your data one view to another by using `Session`

Comment: What products will you be passing and why? is it a category view? then you would do a view based off a category ID and look up products that way.

Comment: But I'm redirecting from  from view . So how can i define in controller? @OMi shah

Comment: Yes ! I want to pass produc id to the other view for showing other related data . @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{{ route('productsnew.index', [ 'products' => $products->pluck('id') ]) }}">some link</a>

Route::get('/some/url/{product_ids}', function($product_ids) {
    Product::whereIn('id', $product_ids)->get();
})->name('prodictsnew.index');
```

But you are much better off using a category id.

```
<a href="{{ route('category.index', [ 'category_id' => $category->id ]) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
```